# Touchpad stop working but it seems enabled

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, touchpad

I have Xubuntu in dual boot with Windows 10, from yesterday the touchpad stopped working on Xubuntu. If I go to the mouse/touchpad settings, it seems to be enabled. I tried to re-enabled it  also via xinput and dfconf-tool, but both of them say that the touchpad is already enabled. Some idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Try **synclient TouchpadOff=0** in your terminal. This is the command for enabling touchpad.  And **synclient TouchpadOff=1** turns it off.

Comment: @Coditoergosum nothing, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `i8042.nopnp` as a kernel parameter at boot. If it works save it permanently in your `/etc/default/grub` file. Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

Comment: still doesn't work